# Changing function module

Tags: python, class, module, runtime, overriding

I've got 2 modules A and B.
module A has nothing inside and module B has a function 'f'
I want to assign function 'f' to module A, but I want override this functions **globals**, because I want this function to use A module variables.

But there I've got some problems. with this simple code:

```
print A
print B
print '---'
from copy import deepcopy 
setattr(A, 'f', deepcopy(B.f))
A.f.__module__ = A
A.f.__globals__['__name__'] = 'A'
print A
print B
```

I've got following result:

```
<module 'A' from '<path>/A/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'B' from '<path>/B/__init__.pyc'>
---
<module 'A' from '<path>/A/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'A' from '<path>/B/__init__.pyc'>
```

Why the name of module is changing when I'm changing only one of functions **globals** key and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Why not put it into A in the first place?

Comment: This is horribly hacky. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to implement something really simple - I've got 2 modules A and B. A has variable x='A' and B has variable x='B'. Additionaly B module has got function 'f', that prints 'self.x'. I want to be able to 'inject' the function into module A, but after calling A.f() I want to get 'A' as a result (as this function would be inside A.

Comment: Sounds to me like you're trying to make modules behave like classes, rather than using classes.  But still, *what* are you trying to implement? I don't mean in terms of Xs, As and Bs, I mean the feature that you are trying to implement.

Comment: delan -> I cannot do this because module B is loded in runtime and it has some functions, that should be 'injected' into A (replacing original A functions). these injected functions should behava as they were implemented in A.

Comment: So is "module A" a builtin module, or something provided by someone, or ...?  *What is it all doing?*

Comment: In general we can say that A is provided by someone or it is part of framework. But the special case, which is connected with my question is described detaily under yours answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might try using [`functools.update_wrapper`](http://docs.python.org/library/functools.html#functools.update_wrapper):

```
A.f = functools.update_wrapper(wrapper=B.f, wrapped=A.f)
```

This will modify `B.f`, though (making it take on aspects of `A.f`, `__module__`, `__name__`, and `__doc__`, refer to `functools` module source code). As you really haven't said what you are trying to accomplish (not how you are trying to accomplish it), I really can't say if this is what you want or not.

Comment: I will try it, thank you.

You're right - I didn't tell what I'm trying to do, because I thought this topic is really big. But what I'm trying to do is to write some tools to reload python modules and theirs dependencies. 
In fact, I'm trying to write something like this idea:
http://doublestar.org/in-place-python-reloading/
The solution is simple - you can delete all modules that you want to reload from sys.modules (making backup first), reload them and then inject all new and changed methods to these backuped modules you've reloaded.

Comment: The best method so far was to reload all modules sorting them with theirs dependencies, but it does not work, when modules depend on themselves recuresively. (module A imports B and B imports A - this situation ispossible if B imports A not on the beggining of its declaration). RollbackImporter is not good solution too in my case (which I wont describe because it is really big).

Comment: I've tested this code, you've posted and it seems not to work :(
Lets concider following code (A has got NO function f):
from copy import deepcopy; import functools; setattr(A, 'f', deepcopy(B.f)); A.f = functools.update_wrapper(wrapper=B.f, wrapped=A.f)
print A.f.__globals__['__name__']

As a result we got 'B', not 'A' :(